# WebsphereMQ with .Net Core 2.2

Tags: c#, .net-core, websphere, ibm-mq

I'm trying to connect to a WebsphereMQ queue using .Net Core 2.2.
I'm really confused on how to do this. I would like some clarification before showing what I'm trying (and failing):

- Which lib should I use and how to get it? (NMS? AMQP? WebsphereClient?)

  - I have seen some examples that aparentlly use some DLL that comes when you install WebsphereMQ (???). Is that correct? Do I need to install WebsphereMQ? (right now I have it in a remote server which I can connect to the queue I need).

What I have tried so far was installing the [WebSphereMQClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebSphereMqClient/) and trying to connect to the queue with the following code:

```
    public void StartListener()
    {
        try
        {
            var xff = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
            var cf = xff.CreateConnectionFactory();
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, WebsphereMqHost);
            cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, WebsphereMqPort);
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, WebsphereMqChannel);
            cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, WebsphereMqQueueManager);
            cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);

            var conn = cf.CreateConnection();
            var sess = conn.CreateSession(false, AcknowledgeMode.AutoAcknowledge);
            var queue = sess.CreateQueue(QueueName);
            var consumer = sess.CreateConsumer(queue);

            consumer.MessageListener = OnWebsphereMsg;

            conn.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            _logger.LogError(e);
        }
    }
```

But I get an exception on the first line:

```
System.Exception: Fatal error. Failed to initialize XMSFactoryFactory ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsFactoryFactoryImpl' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'IBM.XMS.Util.Tr' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'IBM.XMS.Util.ConfigMgr' threw an exception. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.AppDomainSetup System.AppDomain.get_SetupInformation()'.
   at IBM.XMS.Util.ConfigMgr..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBM.XMS.Util.Tr.ResolveTraceSpec()
   at IBM.XMS.Util.Tr.LoadTraceConfig()
   at IBM.XMS.Util.Tr..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBM.XMS.Util.Tr.Register(Type aClass, String group, String resourceBundleName)
   at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsFactoryFactoryImpl..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBM.XMS.Client.Impl.XmsFactoryFactoryImpl.GetClientFactory(Int32 connectionType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at IBM.XMS.XMSFactoryFactory.GetXmsFactory(Int32 connectionType)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBM.XMS.XMSFactoryFactory.GetXmsFactory(Int32 connectionType)
   at IBM.XMS.XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(Int32 connectionType)
   at MyApp.Integrations.Configurations.WebsphereMqIntegrationsManager.StartListener(ListenersEnum listener, Dictionary`2 parameters).
```

I have notice that the WebsphereMqClient is not compliant with .NET Standard. Is this error caused because of it? How can I connect to Websphere with my .NET Core app?

Thanks,

Comment: I would suggest the downloading the MQ v9.1.1 Redist client, .NET standard support was added at this version.  https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24044791

Comment: This knowledge center link details the new library names: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q132490_.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer @JoshMc. I would like to ask you the same thing I asked subbaraoc. Can you please check it below?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

amqmxmsstd.dll is the library that has to be used and it is available from MQ v9.1.1. Following is the infocenter link which talks about using XMS with Microsoft .NET Core.
[Using XMS with Microsoft .NET Core](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.xms.doc/xms_q132500.htm)

You would need both amqmdnetstd.dll and amqmxmsstd.dll for developing XMS .NET applications and both these dll's are built using .NET Standard.Following infocenter link talks about the framework used to build these libraries.
[Installing IBM MQ classes for .NET Standard](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.xms.doc/xms_q132500.htm)

As Josh pointed out,you can use MQ Redist client to get libraries. 
Download "9.1.1.0-IBM-MQC-Redist-Win64" from  [IBM MQ Redist clients](https://www-945.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/swg/selectFixes?parent=ibm%7EWebSphere&product=ibm/WebSphere/WebSphere%20MQ&release=9.1.1&platform=All&function=fixId&fixids=9.1.*-IBM-MQC-*,9.1.*-IBM-MQ-Install-Java-All,9.1.*-IBM-MQ-Java-InstallRA&useReleaseAsTarget=true&includeSupersedes=1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @subbaraoc. The only thing I can't get my head around is how do I get this DLLs (sorry if this is stupid :S). I couldn't find on the links you posted. They seem to suggest installing the whole WebsphereMQ...? Do I really need it in order to just get the DLL (which I would simply copy from the instalation directory)? Isn't there a simple Nuget package with it?

Comment: As Josh pointed out you can use redistributable package which you don't have to install.You can download it and unzip the package.Following link has more info on redistributable client
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ins.doc/q122882_.htm

Comment: Thanks @subbaraoc, will try this first thing tomorrow and come back to (hopefully) check as the answer! (Y)

Comment: Since verion 9.1.4 of the new netstandard client, a NuGet package is made available by IBM: https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBMMQDotnetClient