# IBM MQ and .NET Core application

Tags: .net-core, ibm-mq

I am writing a .NET Core (2.1) Windows Service which will be listening for messages from IBM MQ.

Could anyone point me to a link to a repository with an example, article or at least decent documentation?

Comment: You will need the 9.1 CDS release (9.1.2 is the latest) this is where IBM has added .NET Standard support.  Check out the [[tag:ibm-mq]] tag wiki for a link to the 9.1 knowledge center and search for .NET standard to find the documentation.  The Redistributable client install will have all the dlls that you need.  This question is to broad for stackoverflow so I am voting to close it as such.  If you have more specific questions please post them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249683/webspheremq-with-net-core-2-2) other SO post explaining how to obtain the IBM MQ .NET client libraries.

That being said, IBM has a nice page on [Getting started with IBM MQ classes for .NET](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q029260_.htm) and [IBM MQ samples](https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/sample-code/).